# Difference Between Tubeless Tire and Tube Tire?

Tags: tires

I'd like to know whether tubed tires or tubeless tires are most puncture resistant and last the longest.  Can I use tubes in a car that was meant for tubeless tires?  Can I put tubes inside tires that are meant to be tubeless?

Comment: Most tubeless tyres are designed not to have tubes fitted - and if tubes are fitted they can overheat and fail

Comment: ok good solar mike thank you, which is more protection while puncture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 40 years of driving, I have found that the frequency of punctures is reduced : basically due to the quality of tyres improving, the strength / resistance of the tyres and also using tyres that are in good condition and kept at the correct pressures.

Most tubeless tyres are designed not to have tubes fitted - and if tubes are fitted they can overheat and fail - a decent tyre fitter will know what can be done.

If you are suffering lots of punctures, then you need to make sure your tyres are in good condition, inflated correctly either with or without tubes as appropriate. After that, then the condition of the roads and objects left in the roads comes into play and, for that, we can't do much...

Comment: Thank you so much Solar Mike for help me out the question you best :)

Comment: OT, how old are you?

Comment: I was driving at 10 .... and nothing had power steering...

Answer (score 2):

Tubeless tyres have a different design to tube tyres, as they are designed to seal against the edge of the rim, which a tube tyre doesn't have to do. Tubeless tyres often also have strengthening ribs on the inside, which will rub against a tube if a tube is fitted to them, shortening the life of the tube.

If you are suffering frequent punctures due to road conditions, I'd look at getting reinforced tyres - these have thicker sidewalls and so are more puncture resistant. They are often sold for use on vans or smaller 4x4s.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick c good think about the tires, what you tell, which is good tire, tube or tubeless, which is your chooses?

Comment: That very much depends on what is available in your locality (and in the right size for your car) - I would avoid the very cheap ones, then search the internet for reviews of the rest to see what people say about them. I find that different makes of tyre suit different vehicles and different driving styles, so it's very difficult to make any sort of recommendation

Answer (score 1):

If you have frequent punctures go for self sealing tyres like Contiseal by continental tyres or same tech of michelin self-seal tyres. At least there will be no punctures in tread area for 3 years. But it is also important to know which type of vehicle your driving? Whether it is light truck for loading or a family sedan. Conduct pre-trip inspections and maintain proper inflation pressure.